# How to create Drag and drop product by category in Magento

Tags: magento, drag-and-drop, categories

When I drag the `<li>` element of product into first position or any other position and then refresh the page it will revert back to previous position

This is the file I've edited:
magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

I just changed the ul from `<ul class="products-grid">` to

```
<ul id="sortable" class="products-grid">
```

now its working but only one `<ul>`

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
```

This is the link where I got the code from:

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: Start implementation and ask question about issues u faced while coding.. or else no one can help you.

Comment: Ok  Mr. Babak T thanks !

Comment: i will start the implementation

Comment: Thank you Mr. Babak T sir for edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the position of the list somewhere to prevent falling back to previous position after you refresh the page..

Normally people save the order of the list in a field of the specific table which the list is coming from. Then later on when you want to SELECT the rows you will need to ORDER BY that order_field.

Since you are using Magento it would be not an easy task to create this feature unless you find a plugin or library.